# How to force an archive to store true_type even if it is this_type?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

This topic deals with boost serialization.

When I serialize a polymorphic object, an archive stores the information about true_type (i.e. the concrete type of an object) only if it is not equal to this_type (i.e. the type of the serialized object).

I.e. : the type of the serialized object is stored only if it is serialized from a base class.

How can I force the archive to always store the type?

Let's illustrate with a sample, I'm not sure the above text is so obvious...:

Let's have 2 classes serializable:

```
class Base { ... };
class Leaf : public Base { ... };
```

If I do :

```
std::stringstream ios(std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);

Base* b = new Leaf();
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ios);
ar & b;
```

Then the archive contains:

22 serialization::archive 9 0 4 **Leaf** 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

It contains the Leaf concrete type information.

However if I do :

```
Leaf* b = new Leaf();
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ios);
ar & b;
```

Then the archive contains:

22 serialization::archive 9 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

It doesn't contain Leaf type info.

How can I produce an archive **WITH** the true_type all the type?

I search 2 ways:
    -  calling a method of archive type (register_type, save_pointer, ...) unsuccessfully
    -  directly change the boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp file:
in struct polymorphic, in function template static void save(Archive &ar, T & t)
I comment out

```
if(*this_type == *true_type){
    const basic_pointer_oserializer * bpos = register_type(ar, t);
    ar.save_pointer(vp, bpos);
    return;
}
```

unsuccessfully.

Thank you for help.

Nicolas.

PS : a word about why I'm trying to do that.
When the true_type is "registered" (I'm not sure register is the right word), we can deserialize the object to any base class.
Example:

```
//SERIALIZATION:
Leaf* leaf = new Leaf();
ar & leaf;

//DESERIALIZATION:
Base* b = 0;
ar & b; // would work only if Leaf has been saved in the archive as true_type
```

For tools in a multi-team project, it' powerfull : data for tests has been serialized by a team, and the other team can deserialize, let's say an image, to the interface class IImage without asking: what was the true_tyep : an Image3D, an AImage2D, an Image2DRGB, an Image2DRAW, and so on.

Comment: You may want to trim your question down... It may get better answers with a much smaller question size.